# How to generate time between given two range in android?

Tags: android, datetime, for-loop, spinner

I am developing an application in android. I got stuck at this point:

User selects time range using a spinner. Then it displays times in between a given range with a specific time interval. I tried and came well but after 12 we have to print 1 in time which i am unable to do.Adding a example below.I don't know how to implement it.
For example.
If a user selects 9-2 we have to generate like

9.00 9.30 10.00 10.30 11.00 11.30 12.00 12.30 1.00 1.30 2.00

Can some one help me?
Even just a idea is enough.
If you need my coding I will add it here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which generate time intervals int setted range. You just need to call method from `TimeIntervalHelper`.

Here is the code:

```
public class TimeIntervalHelper {
    public static void generateTimeInterval(final ArrayList<String> intervals, final int startHour, final boolean isStartHalf, int endHour, final boolean isEndHalf) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, startHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, isStartHalf ? 30 : 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        endHour = endHour == 12 ? 0 : endHour;
        while (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) != endHour)
            intervals.add(getInterval(calendar));
        intervals.add(getInterval(calendar));

        if (isEndHalf)
            intervals.add(getInterval(calendar));
    }

    public static void generateTimeInterval(final ArrayList<String> intervals, final int startHour, int endHour) {
        generateTimeInterval(intervals, startHour, false, endHour, false);
    }

    private static String getInterval(final Calendar calendar) {
        final String interval = String.format(
                "%d.%02d",
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) != 0 ? calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) : 12,
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        );
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        return interval;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample:

```
final ArrayList<String> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
TimeIntervalHelper.generateTimeInterval(intervals, 9, 2); // Generate from 9 to 2
TimeIntervalHelper.generateTimeInterval(intervals, 9, false, 2, true); // Generate from 9 to 2.30
```

Comment: Wow man! unbelievable! Works like a charm. One thing is,is it possible to generate like 9 to 2.30 instead of 9 to 2?

Comment: Again WOW!! saved me alots! THANKS A MILLION!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the formatting, have a look at [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Example (slightly modified)

```
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");
  String text = date.format(formatter);
  LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

You should be able to manage the conversion to `LocalDate` ;-). If not, say so (and post code what you tried).

For the date generation, here is some code. This is a bit harder using the old date API, but:

```
long intervalMillis;
Date startingDate, endDate;
List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
dateList.add(date);
while ( date.before(endDate) || date.equals(endDate) ) {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + intervalMillis);
    dateList.append(date);
}
```

If you want to use the [new time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), you could do

```
Instant start, end;
Duration increment;
Instant moment = start;
List<Instant> dateList = new ArrayList<Instant>();
dateList.add(moment);
while ( moment.isBefore(end) || moment.equals(end) ) {
    moment = moment.plus(increment);
    dateList.add(moment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using date format of 12 hours

Please change your date format to 24 hours and then check it will work..

Thanks..